# How to remove duplicates in a text string with Power Query

Tags: powerquery

As my subject mentioned, after doing a few step (groupby , filter , combine text ...), I have an issue with removing duplicate in the same cell in power query.
example: column "cc_emails" has many row, but each row have some duplicated email due to Text.Combine step before:

```
sth like that:  "Giang.Phan@abc.com, thao.tran@abc.com, Khoa.Vu@abc.com, Vn.Offset@abc.com, Giang.Phan@abc.com, thao.tran@abc.com, Khoa.Vu@abc.com, Vn.Offset@abc.com"
```

I would like to 1 email will only appear once in the list? Can someone help look this ?
output expected:

```
"Giang.Phan@abc.com,thao.tran@abc.com, Khoa.Vu@abc.com, Vn.Offset@abc.com"
```

##update my Query Editor:

```
let
    Source = Exchange.Contents("giang.phan@abc.com"),
    Mail1 = Source{[Name="Mail"]}[Data],
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Mail1,{"DateTimeSent", "DateTimeReceived", "Folder Path", "Subject", "Sender", "DisplayTo", "DisplayCc", "ToRecipients", "CcRecipients", "BccRecipients", "Importance", "Categories", "IsRead", "HasAttachments", "Attachments", "Preview", "Attributes", "Body", "Id"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns", each [DateTimeReceived] > #datetime(2021, 12, 29, 0, 0, 0) and [DateTimeReceived] < #datetime(2022, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0)),
    #"Expanded ToRecipients" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "ToRecipients", {"Address"}, {"ToRecipients.Address"}),
    #"Expanded CcRecipients" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded ToRecipients", "CcRecipients", {"Address"}, {"CcRecipients.Address"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded CcRecipients",{"BccRecipients", "Importance", "Categories", "IsRead", "HasAttachments", "Attachments", "Preview", "Attributes"}),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Id", "DateTimeSent", "DateTimeReceived", "Folder Path", "Subject", "Sender", "DisplayTo", "DisplayCc", "ToRecipients.Address", "CcRecipients.Address", "Body"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Reordered Columns1", {"Id", "DateTimeSent", "DateTimeReceived", "Folder Path", "Subject", "DisplayTo", "DisplayCc"}, {{"cc_address", each Text.Combine([CcRecipients.Address],", "), type text}, {"to_address", each Text.Combine([ToRecipients.Address],", "), type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows", {"Id", "DateTimeSent", "DateTimeReceived", "Folder Path", "DisplayTo", "DisplayCc", "cc_address", "to_address"}, {{"Last_time receive", each List.Max([DateTimeReceived]), type datetime}, {"Last_subject", each List.Max([Subject]), type nullable text}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Grouped Rows1",{"Id", "DateTimeSent", "DateTimeReceived", "Folder Path", "DisplayTo", "DisplayCc", "cc_address", "to_address", "Last_time receive", "Last_subject"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the text by delimiter, select the distinct list values, then recombine as a string:

```
let
    Source = "Giang.Phan@abc.com, thao.tran@abc.com, Khoa.Vu@abc.com, Vn.Offset@abc.com, Giang.Phan@abc.com, thao.tran@abc.com, Khoa.Vu@abc.com, Vn.Offset@abc.com",
    #"Distinct Values" = Text.Combine(List.Distinct(Text.Split(Source, ", ")),", ")
in
    #"Distinct Values"
```

***Edit after question update:***

In your case, you can simply change this line:

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Reordered Columns1", {"Id", "DateTimeSent", "DateTimeReceived", "Folder Path", "Subject", "DisplayTo", "DisplayCc"}, {{"cc_address", each Text.Combine([CcRecipients.Address],", "), type text}, {"to_address", each Text.Combine([ToRecipients.Address],", "), type text}}),
```

to include the `List.Distinct` function, and return only distinct address values:

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Reordered Columns1", {"Id", "DateTimeSent", "DateTimeReceived", "Folder Path", "Subject", "DisplayTo", "DisplayCc"}, {{"cc_address", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([CcRecipients.Address]),", "), type text}, {"to_address", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([ToRecipients.Address]),", "), type text}}),
```

Comment: Hi @Olly , Thank you for your assist.  this is my power query editor  (Table.SelectColumns(#"Grouped Rows1",{"Id", "DateTimeSent", "DateTimeReceived", "Folder Path", "DisplayTo", "DisplayCc", "cc_address", "to_address", "Last_time receive", "Last_subject"}) , Could you please assist how i can input the code above to the current power query ? i just need only to apply for cc_address column

Comment: Please edit your question and include your query code there.

Comment: I have updated query code.

Comment: And I have edited my answer. You can simply insert the `List.Distinct` function into your `#'"Grouped Rows"` step.